# Botón sobresaliente de Drawer MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, navigation-drawer

necesito lograr el siguiente resultado para un Drawer hecho con Material UI, un botón que sobresalga del Drawer, que se visualice la mitad dentro del Drawer y la otra mitad por fuera, este botón cumplirá con la función de hacer el Drawer más pequeño, de forma que se aproveche más el ancho de la pantalla para mostrar los diferentes elementos del dashboard:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo al intentarlo mi resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En donde se puede notar que el botón se recorta al salirse del Drawer, no sobresale, aquí dejo el código:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled, useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import MuiDrawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import MuiAppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mail';
import { PaperCustom } from './SidebarElement';
import { Icon, Image, RowCenter, TextOpenSans, TextSatoshi, TextSatoshiBold } from '../../styled/AppElement';
import logo_sidebar from '../../assets/logos/logo_sidebar.svg'
import avatar_profile from '../../assets/icons/avatar_profile.svg'
import check_verified from '../../assets/icons/check_verified.svg'
import { Fab } from '@mui/material';
import { ChevronRight } from '@mui/icons-material';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const openedMixin = (theme) => ({
  width: drawerWidth,
  transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
  }),
  overflowX: 'hidden',
});

const closedMixin = (theme) => ({
  transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  overflowX: 'hidden',
  width: `calc(${theme.spacing(7)} + 1px)`,
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    width: `calc(${theme.spacing(8)} + 1px)`,
  },
});

const DrawerHeader = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
  ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
}));

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open',
})(({ theme, open }) => ({
  zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  ...(open && {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  }),
}));

const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
  ({ theme, open }) => ({
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    ...(open && {
      ...openedMixin(theme),
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': openedMixin(theme),
    }),
    ...(!open && {
      ...closedMixin(theme),
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': closedMixin(theme),
    }),
  }),
);

export default function Sidebar() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex'}}>
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open} sx={{position: 'relative', overflow: 'visible'}}>
        <Fab size='small' sx={{position: 'absolute', width: '35px', height: '35px', transform: 'transform: translateY(-50%)', top: '50%', right: '-15px'}}>
            <ChevronRight/>
        </Fab>
        <PaperCustom>
            <div>
                <Box sx={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', padding: '25px 0px', gap: '10px'}}>
                    <Image src={logo_sidebar} alt='logo' width={150}/>
                    <Icon src={avatar_profile} alt='avatar' width={80}/>
                    <RowCenter style={{gap: '8px'}}>
                        <Icon src={check_verified} alt='check' width={20}/>
                        <TextSatoshi>Verficado</TextSatoshi>
                    </RowCenter>
                    <TextSatoshiBold style={{color: 'white'}}>Alfa Intech</TextSatoshiBold>
                </Box>
                <List>
                {['Inicio', 'Herramientas', 'Configuración', 'Ayuda', 'Salir'].map((text, index) => (
                    <ListItem key={text} disablePadding sx={{ display: 'block' }}>
                    <ListItemButton
                        sx={{
                        minHeight: 48,
                        justifyContent: open ? 'initial' : 'center',
                        px: 2.5,
                        }}
                        onClick={index % 2 === 0 ? handleDrawerClose : handleDrawerOpen}
                    >
                        <ListItemIcon
                        sx={{
                            minWidth: 0,
                            mr: open ? 3 : 'auto',
                            justifyContent: 'center',
                        }}
                        >
                        {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                        </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
                    </ListItemButton>
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
                </List>
            </div>
            
            <div style={{marginBottom: '5%'}}>
                <TextOpenSans style={{fontSize: '12px', color: 'white'}}>©QMASTER All Right Reserved 2023</TextOpenSans>
            </div>
        </PaperCustom>
      </Drawer>
      </>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Si no me equivoco puedes insertar un snippet de React desde el botón con `<>`. Se agradecería que cargues el código de esa manera ya que aparece un botón para previsualizar el resultado.